# osx jenkins homebrew installation - maven and java configuration

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed jenkins, java and maven via homebrew:

brew install jenkins
brew install maven
brew cask install java8

and started jenkins like:

brew services start jenkins.

I was able to launch jenkins console and write jobs.
My jenkins job build war and deploys to local tomcat.
IN build it does a "mvn clean package" and deploys it into local tomcat container.

But when i run job fails saying:

- mvn clean package
  /var/folders/gq/ytz5wzr55076lkywnf65c5jr0000gn/T/jenkins9060176560767855183.sh: line 2: mvn: command not found
  Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
  Finished: FAILURE

So I configured maven in global configurations like below:
[Maven Configuration - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBC72.png)

But still the build fails.
Can anyone help me please?
Configure maven on jenkins installed through homebrew.